# Works .htaccess with Meteor?

Tags: .htaccess, meteor

Is it possible to use .htaccess and .htpasswd with a meteor application?

And can I use it, if I deploy my app on xyz.meteor.com?

I've tried it on xyz.meteor.com, but it didn't work:

```
AuthUserFile /meteor/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Password"
AuthType Basic
<Limit GET>
require valid-user
</Limit>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.htaccess` isn't designed to work with Meteor & it would basically ignore it.

If you want to password protect a directory you might be better of using Apache or using an npm module that would give the HTTP routes with a password for a directory or route:

At the moment such a package doesn't exist on atmosphere but you could build one using an npm module:

A couple of examples of npm modules which should be capable of doing this

- https://npmjs.org/package/kerouac-htaccess
- https://npmjs.org/package/polpetta
- https://npmjs.org/package/http-auth

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using [meteor-roles](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles) and let only admins see all pages of the system.
Everyone else see only the login screen.

Comment: haha even my login screen is kinda revealing, but good to know the option exists, thanks.